# Add new ODBC driver libs to PHP on OS X 10.6?

Tags: php, mac-osx, postgresql, odbc

I'm trying to access a PostgreSQL datasource via ODBC from the installed stock PHP (OS X 10.6). Queries just hang, and I'm suspecting it can't find the PostgreSQL driver library which was installed via MacPorts.

I've compiled and installed the psqlODBC drivers from source using this configuration:

```
--prefix=/usr/local --with-iodbc
--with-libpq=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
```

I have successfully created and tested the ODBC connection using iodbctest.

Do I need to do something to get Apache/PHP to see libpq?